# Comparing element in list and string

Tags: python, string-comparison, helper

I am just learning python, and I come across the question where i have to read a file and see search for a word

my code is

```
Search_Word = input("Type your search word : ")
file = open(input("Your file name"), 'r')
read_line = file.readlines()
file.close()

def isPartOf(read_line, Search_Word):
    x = False
    for i in range (0, len(read_line)):
        if(str(read_line[i) == Search_Word):
            x = True

    return x


isPartOf(read_line, Search_Word)
print(isPartOf(read_line, Search_Word))
```

The problem is that after I change every line into a list then compare every element in a list to user input (What i have to search)
problem is that even though element in list and user input match exactly the program does not recognize them as same thing...

Comment: `if Search_Word in read_line[i]:` which is True when `Search_Word` is a substring of `read_line[i]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace

```
for i in range (0, len(read_line)):
    if(str(read_line[i) == Search_Word):
```

by

```
for i in read_line:
    if i.strip('\n') == Search_Word:
```